# NoMethodError in StaticPages#home when attempting to list database query

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Ruby noob here, I created a search form  and I am trying to query a db and display the results. I am getting NoMethodError in StaticPages#home 
along with....
/home/action/Projects/CodonCoderTest5/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Where am I going wrong?

layouts/StaticPages/home

```
<h1>StaticPages#home</h1>
<% @data_bases.each do |list| %>
     <div class="list">
         <h1 class="list-mrnaCodon"><%= link_to list.mrnaCodon %></h1>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
class DataBaseController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def index
     if params[:search]
         @data_bases = Match.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
     else
         @data_bases = Match.order("created_at DESC")
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: its always better to post exact error trace than parsing it yourself.

Comment: @shivam what do you mean by that exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `@data_bases` in your view is evaluating to nil. That makes sense, since the only way the view for `StaticPages#home` would have access to that variable is if it were set in the corresponding controller action (i.e. the `home` method on the `StaticPagesController`). Looks like you're only setting that variable on the `DataBaseController`.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def home
    if params[:search]
      @data_bases = Match.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @data_bases = Match.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: I've only defined the various pages in StaticPagesController, other than that it's an empty. Do you mind showing a snippet of code about what you mean? thanks

Comment: edited the response to illustrate. Without initializing that variable in the `home` action on the `StaticPagesController`, the view for `static_pages/home` has no way of knowing about it. (I'll bet your current code would work fine on the `data_base/index` view)

Comment: Implemented the code you posted, unfortunately it still doesnt work. It does however return this error "NameError in StaticPagesController#home". thanks for the help